# bool colon initialization

Tags: c++, boolean

While reading some C++ code, I saw and was confused by this little line in a class:

```
bool x:1;
```

In debug builds, I noticed that 'x' is initialized as 'false', but I can not find any documentation about that.  Can anyone tell me what this syntax does?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it's a **bit field**. read up on bit fields in your c++ textbook.

the initialization to `false` is independent of the declaration. whether it is guaranteed by your code depends on your code (not given).

the c++ standard gives the compiler some leeway for integer and enumeration bitfields of size 1: storing the value `1` in such a field, you may get out the value `-1`. happily this applies only to fields of size 1, and it does not apply to a field of type `bool`.